# How to display the selected option while refreshing the webpage using <mat-select > in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm selecting a option using mat-select.But when the page is reloaded,by default it is not showing the selected option.How to display the previously selected option when a user visits the page again.

**component.html**

```
 <mat-tab label="Priority">
        <div class="form-group row form-group2" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
          <label  class="col-sm-5 col-form-label ">Select Priority :</label>
       <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" >
          <mat-label>Priority</mat-label>
          <mat-select   (valueChange)="setPriority($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let priority of priorities" [value]="priority">
              {{priority.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        
      </div>
          </mat-tab>
```

**component.ts**

```
 setPriority(prior:any):void{
   this.apiService.assignPriority(prior.value,this.gigID).subscribe((res)=>{
    if(res.status == true){
      console.log('assingend succes',this.gigID);
    }
    else{
      console.log('no succes',this.gigID);
    }
   
  });
   
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsnncp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the value to your mat-select using `[(ngModel)]="defaultValue"` or a `[formControl]="yourFromControl"`.
[You can read more here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)